# Copying visual studio 2010 installed extensions options to another computer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, copy, settings

I have visual studio 2010 installed and configured with some extensions at my home computer. Now i want to copy all installed extensions settings from my home computer to work computer, how can i do that?

I can copy visual studio settings via import/export dialog but this not work for extensions settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual studio extension settings are stored in the registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\DialogPage\<extension>
```

if they implement the default extension settings mechanism.

Otherwise you'll have to go to the individual extension website to see where they store their settings.

Answer (score 13):

I would look in this directory

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions`

That is where the extensions are stored, copy that to your new PC.

I'm not sure if this will work 100% but you can give it a shot.

Comment: I tried this already, this folder contains only extensions itself without settings.

Comment: This was useful to me as I had a corrupt extension that I needed to manually delete.

Comment: This was useful to me as I had reinstalled my PC. So I was able to look at all the files i saved from my last install to see what EXT i had. Now I save all my extensions in a special VS folder install/settings/saved-www-pages-vs-hacks just in case this happens again. I guess you just have to be diligent about things to reduce the risk of that scenario in the future..

Answer (score 2):

It is under one of the directories in AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation. Each extension has a user.config file stored.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2013 you can find them by this (not sure if this also works for VS 2010 but maybe it helps someone):

```
 var config1 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
 MessageBox.Show("Config path: " + config1.FilePath);
```