# Visual Studio extension configuration location

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I have [this extension](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/vsfileexplorer) installed in VS2012, but it crashes VS when I try to open it (View > Other Windows > Mindscape File Explorer)

Is there a standard location in the registry or elsewhere where VS extensions store settings? I had set the home folder of the extension to a sym link that no longer exists and I think I might be the cause of the issue. I want to try and reset the extension settings.

I've uninstalled VS, wiped some entries from the registry, removed VS appdata folders etc, nothing worked so far.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14262321/736079

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying visual studio 2010 installed extensions options to another computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936346/copying-visual-studio-2010-installed-extensions-options-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found settings for the extension in an xml file named as **user.config**
under [user_home]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\DefaultDomain_Url_(....)\10.0.(....)\

Comment: Fantastic, I was able to clear the bad home path and the extension works again!

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard, no. It's typically written under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio, but extensions can and do put things in other places.