# How to pass nuget packages without actually copying them?

Tags: c++, nuget, nuget-package

The title may be ambiguous but hopefully I can explain my question.
I have a cpp solution and have installed a lot of packages in it using nuget (boost, openssl, jsoncpp, cpprestsdk.. etc) and I want to send this solution to a friend.
But copying the full solution is like 7GB including packages.

So the question is - is there a way to pass the packages.config file or some other way so that he can just download all packages or restore with nuget?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951439/visual-studio-extension-configuration-location

Comment: @vish not really

Comment: Okay, I think this might; assuming you are using project that uses `PackageReference` : https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/main/docs/consume-packages/Package-Restore.md#restore-using-visual-studio